# Why does link list function crash when values are in ascending order?

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I am puzzled by the behaviour of my program when traversing a linked list.

I'm writing a function that is supposed to check if a linked list of integers is in ascending order, returning 1 if it is and 0 otherwise.  Here is what I have so far:

```
int isasc(NodePtr top){

    NodePtr curr=top;

    if(top=NULL) return 0;

    while(curr!=NULL){

        if(curr->num > curr->next->num){ 
            return 0;
        }
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    return 1 ;
}
```

it works when the list is not in ascending order but crashes when it is. Do you have any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: How do you know that `curr->next` is not `NULL`?

Comment: A theoretical question: is an empty list ascending or descending? Next question: why would you want the NULL test *before* entering the loop? Why would the caller call this function with an empty list?

Answer (score 3):

You also have:

```
if(top=NULL) return 0;
```

That's assigning `NULL` to `top` and the condition is treated as FALSE.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things that is strange with this code. The reason why it crashes is because you are accessing `curr->next->num` without checking that `curr->next` is `NULL`.

There are also some other things that doesn't make sense. The pointer `top` is not used and it is also not compared to `NULL` but **set** to `NULL` and that statement will always evaluate to `NULL`, which is false.

Instead do:

```
int isasc(NodePtr curr)
{
    if(curr == NULL) return 0;

    while(curr->next != NULL)
    {
        if(curr->num > curr->next->num) 
            return 0;

        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `curr != NULL` check in the loop, since you already verified it is not going to be `NULL`, in the `if` check and the fact we don't enter the `while` if `curr->next` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

It's crashing because at some point `curr->next` is `NULL`. Your code only "works" for the out-of-order case because the function mercifully terminates before reaching the end of the list.

To fix your program, check that `curr->next` is not `NULL` before dereferencing it.